# NAO robot behaviors activate without being triggered

Tags: nao-robot, choregraphe

NAO robot behaviors trigger without being prompted by user. Sometimes seems to get stuck in some kind of loop where it constantly activates random behaviors without listening to the user at all.

Behaviors are made in the  Choregraph SDK. I have trigger phrases set and trigger condition is something of the like shown below. I have tried removing and reinstalling behaviors, but the problem persists.

```
('Launchpad/numPeopleZone1'>0 ~ 5) & ('Launchpad/PreviousBehavior' != '<activity-name>/behavior_1')
```

I expect the behaviors to only trigger when users say trigger phrases, but they trigger on their own, often nonstop, ignoring user input.

Answer (score 0):

After some more work I realized what the problem was. NEVER set trigger conditions. They allow the robot to launch activities autonomously (without user input), which made a mess of my project. Trigger conditions should only be set if you want your robot to start doing the activity on its own.